# Making new type of errors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await

I occasionally forget to use the await keyword, e.g.:

```
const foo = bar();
// instead of
const foo = await bar();
```

Those bugs are difficult to spot. Which methods, libraries or tools are available to prevent those kind of bugs?

Comment: There is no particular method to prevent forgetting an 'await' tag. However, WebStorm can help you identify those missing keywords.

Comment: It's often perfectly valid to not await a promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a linter like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/). If you integrate the tool with your IDE/Editor and you enable the default set of rules (or your own) it'll make your life a lot easier.

I'm pretty sure your example falls into the rule [no-floating-promises](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md), which disallows the usage of promises without proper handling. In your case `bar()` returns a promise but there's no `await` or `then` to handle the result.

To enable that rule you'll have to install ESLint plus the [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint)
 plugin. I'll also strongly recommend you to use TypeScript over JavaScript, since it'll catch a series of bugs during development and you can transpile your TS code into common JS code.